# Как в CardPanel программно добавить новую Card?

Tags: delphi

В Delphi 11 есть CardPanel. Нашёл как программно добавлять в Card строки и столбцы, а вот как добавить саму карту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по исходникам в `Vcl.WinXPanels.pas` у `TCardPanel` есть метод `CreateNewCard`, который создаёт новую `TCard`, помещает в свой список, и возвращает на неё указатель.